# IntelliJ disable usage statistics / data sharing via configuration file

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

The Option to disable data sharing can be changed at any time by the user:

[image]

I want to disable this setting by default for a managed installation of IntelliJ IDEA, ideally via configuration file or registry setting.
How can I do this? I could not find any registry setting or configuration setting so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is already disabled by default.

The state of the option is stored in the `/consentOptions/accepted` file under the data directory which is [platform specific](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/gdpr/Locations.java#L18).

On Windows that would be `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\consentOptions\accepted`.

When the option is enabled, the file will contain something like this:

```
thrd.plugins:1.0:0:1525589497351;rsch.send.usage.stat:1.1:1:1551998109388
```

and the following with the option disabled:

```
thrd.plugins:1.0:0:1525589497351;rsch.send.usage.stat:1.1:0:1551998064076
```

The format is as follows:

```
rsch.send.usage.stat:<version>:<enabled>:<timestamp>
```

You can learn more from the [ConsentOptions.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/gdpr/ConsentOptions.java) source code.